# How to decode message from a canbus (Iptronik)

Tags: python, embedded, can-bus

I retrieve from a canbus the following  message and signal  data (from an Iptronik  sim stg machine).  I coded it with  python, I use the python-can library and I have ubuntu 18.04

The  message /signal retrieved :

```
Timestamp: 1570622811.311113        ID: 0060    S                DLC:  8    e4 7f 55 55 55 55 04 00     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1570622811.811173        ID: 0060    S                DLC:  8    e4 7f 55 55 55 55 0f 06     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1570622812.311224        ID: 0060    S                DLC:  8    e4 7f 55 55 55 55 65 1a     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1570622812.811266        ID: 0060    S                DLC:  8    e4 7f 55 55 55 55 47 0c     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1570622813.311266        ID: 0060    S                DLC:  8    e4 7f 55 55 55 55 2c 58     Channel: can0
Timestamp: 1570622813.811316        ID: 0060    S                DLC:  8    e4 7f 55 55 55 55 20 36     Channel: can0
```

from the dbc file I have this information.

```
BO_ 96 DEVICE_51900450_0: 8 C_51900450
  SG_ Beschleunigung : 0|16@1+ (0.000152590218966964,-5) [-5|5] "V" IPETRONIK_CAN_1
  SG_ Pos : 48|16@1+ (0.000152590218966964,0) [0|10] "V" IPETRONIK_CAN_1
```

when I convert to the 4 first bits and the four last one  I get this number that does not correspond to the dbc file .

```
(228, 127, 3, 0)
(228, 127, 3, 0)
(228, 127, 62, 3)
(228, 127, 162, 16)
(228, 127, 143, 28)
(228, 127, 252, 93)
```

Can you help me or give me some advice to convert properly the signal according to  the dbc instructions.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this might help you...

```
import cantools
import can
from pprint import pprint 

db = cantools.database.load_file('******_dbc.dbc') #path of .dbc file
print( db.messages)
can_bus = can.interface.Bus('can0', bustype='socketcan')
message = can_bus.recv()
for msg in can_bus:
     print ( db.decode_message(msg.arbitration_id, msg.data))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use CAN BUS tools (https://cantools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to load your .DBC file and properly decode your CAN messages:

```
pip install cantools
```

Here's the sample code:

```
>>> import cantools
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> db = cantools.database.load_file('tests/files/dbc/motohawk.dbc')
>>> db.messages
[message('ExampleMessage', 0x1f0, False, 8, 'Example message used as template in MotoHawk models.')]
>>> example_message = db.get_message_by_name('ExampleMessage')
>>> pprint(example_message.signals)
[signal('Enable', 7, 1, 'big_endian', False, 1.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, '-', False, None, {0: 'Disabled', 1: 'Enabled'}, None),
 signal('AverageRadius', 6, 6, 'big_endian', False, 0.1, 0, 0.0, 5.0, 'm', False, None, None, ''),
 signal('Temperature', 0, 12, 'big_endian', True, 0.01, 250, 229.53, 270.47, 'degK', False, None, None, None)]
```

Comment: Thank you it put me on the right track.  I found  in the documentation example to decode the the signal.

Answer (score 1):

In python there is this awesome library https://pypi.org/project/cantools/

You can go through the source code of it to find the fields you need to extract : https://github.com/eerimoq/cantools/tree/f120d35e1523201b6d87e87306457bf1769330e3

All relevant fields for messages and signals can be found out in cantools/database/can/message.py and /database/can/signal.py in this github link

For eg: if you need names and unit of signals you could use signal.name and signal.unit

Sample code to extract these fields:

```
 #**dbc_file** is the full path of dbc 
    db = cantools.database.load_file(dbc_file)
    for msg in db.messages:
        msg_name = msg.name
        msg_id = msg.frame_id
        msg_length = msg.length
        sender = msg.senders
        msg_group = db.get_message_by_name(msg_name)
    
        for signal in msg_group.signals:
            
            #name of signal
            sig_name = signal.name
            #unit of signal
            sig_unit = signal.unit
```

Hope this might help some one!!!